# Multiple urls of git submodule - per remote submodules

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-submodules

I have git repository with two remotes (github and bitbucket). Inside I have submodule, that points accordingly to another github/bitbucket repo.
But in the definition of submodule is url, that is hardcoded. Can I have two of them? Or one per remote? So that my main repo on github points to submodule on github. And my main repo on Bitbucket points to submodule on bitbucket?

```
[submodule "programs/mgr-nancy-demo"]
    path = programs/mgr-nancy-demo
    url = git@github.com:wedkarz/mgr-nancy-demo.git
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It seems you can [use relative URLs for submodules](http://blog.tremily.us/posts/Relative_submodules/). From `git help submodules`:

> ### COMMANDS
>
> #### add
>
> [...]
>
> `<repository>` is the URL of the new submodule’s origin repository. This may be either an absolute URL, or (if it begins with ./ or ../), the location relative to the superproject’s origin repository

So, if you follow the same naming convention in both sites (ie, `github.com/you/parent-project`, `bitbucket.org/you/parent-project`, `github.com/you/child-project` and `bitbucket.org/you/child-project`), you should be able to set the submodule like this:

```
[submodule "programs/mgr-nancy-demo"]
    path = programs/mgr-nancy-demo
    url = ../mgr-nancy-demo.git
```

Test it - YMMV!

Comment: Thank you, very helpful. I thinked that I am only has the problem like this (when transport on sever is different with local), but after read the article I understood that this problem is very common.

Comment: How to clone and initialize a master repo with  relative URLs submodule?