# Using ssh vs https with github submodules

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I would like to set up a public GitHub repo with submodules.  GitHub offers two ways of connecting - `https:...` & `git@...` protocols.  For the team working on the project, `git@...` is much easier to use because we all use proper ssh certificates. But for the casual user who is not a member of the team, `https:...` is the only option.  The git submodules require a full URL.

How can we set up repository submodules so that both the developers and casual contributors can use the system equally well?  Thanks!

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044992/use-different-git-submodule-urls-on-different-machines/41047197#41047197

Comment: Consider whether submodules are the way to go, as opposed to making packages and using a package manager. Many package managers will draw from a Git repository.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Publish your submodules with `https://` protocol but make all your developers to use `ssh://` protocol. Git can [substitute one protocol with the other on the fly](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-urlltbasegtinsteadOf):

```
git config url."ssh://git@".insteadOf https://
```

Answer (score 2):

Building on top of [phd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50299434/13169344), I found that I had to specify `--global` in order to make sure the config applies to the submodules as well. This is the command I ran:

```
git config --global 'url.ssh://git@example.com.insteadOf' 'https://example.com:PORT'
```

*(Posted as an answer since I don't have the reputation to comment)*

Answer (score 1):

First, it is not the "git protocol", but actually the [SSH one](https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-SSH-Protocol), with URL like `git@github.com:user:repo`.
(there actually is a [git protocol](https://git-scm.com/book/no-nb/v1/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols#The-Git-Protocol), no longer used these days)

Second, keep the URLs as https for the submodules: it is easy to cache the credentials (username/password) with a credential manager (like [GCM for Windows](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows)).
But that means those [users need to be added as contributors](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/) (whether or not you are using HTTPS, or SSH URLs)