# Define two ways to pull git sub-modules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a git REPO that used as submodule.
I also have two group of users, one group able to pull that REPO only as Kerberos the other only via SSH.

Is there any way to define on GIT level two way to pull the SUBMODULE by specific criteria ?

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ssh vs https with github submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50282837/using-ssh-vs-https-with-github-submodules)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+insteadof

Comment: Yes, let some of your developers use `ssh://` directly, other's use [`insteadOf`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-urlltbasegtinsteadOf) and Kerberos.