# Permission denied while recursively clone git repo with submodules through ssh on MacOS

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, git-submodules, git-clone

I am trying to clone a repository with submodules from gitlab using ssh authentication from MacOS. I am able to read the main repository without a problem, but my authentication does not seem to be passed to the submodules, even though I should have access to them. I receive the following output on the `git clone --recursive` command:

```
Cloning into '<main repo name>'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3296, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (45/45), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (37/37), done.
remote: Total 3296 (delta 23), reused 23 (delta 8), pack-reused 3251
Receiving objects: 100% (3296/3296), 154.40 MiB | 18.25 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (493/493), done.
Submodule '<submodule>' (https://:@gitlab.cern.ch:8443/<path to remote submodule>) registered for path '<submodule>'
Cloning into '<path to local submodule>'...
remote: HTTP Basic: Access denied
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://gitlab.cern.ch:8443/<path to remote submodule>'
fatal: clone of 'https://:@gitlab.cern.ch:8443/<path to remote submodule>' into submodule path '<path to local submodule>' failed
```

I also find that the `.gitmodules` file contains the following lines:

```
[submodule "<submodule>"]
        path = <submodule>
        url = https://:@gitlab.cern.ch:8443/<path to remote submodule>
```

It seems that the main repository is accessed correctly through ssh, but the submodule wants to use HTTP authentication, which is not an option for me. The clone worked just fine on a separate Linux machine (I need the repository on both), so I also wonder if this is a Mac-specific issue.

Is there a way to force the submodule to be downloaded with ssh authentication? Or otherwise fix the download?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50299434/7976758

Comment: `git config url."ssh://git@".insteadOf https://` or more specific: `git config --global url."ssh://gitlab.cern.ch/".insteadOf https://:@gitlab.cern.ch:8443/`

Comment: Unfortunately this still results in a `Permission denied (publickey)` error even though I have permission to read the submodule repository

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure, the HTTPS URL seem to be invalid

```
 https://:@gitlab.cern.ch:8443
         ^^^
```

And If it actually includes a `:@`, that means your *global* `git config` should be:

```
 git config --global url."gitlab.cern.ch:".insteadOf https://:@gitlab.cern.ch:8443/
                                                             ^^
```

With a `~/.ssh/config` file including (following the `Remotes in CERN GitLab` page)

```
Host gitlab.cern.ch
  Hostname gitlab.cern.ch
  Port 7999
  User git
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yourPrivateKey
```

With, as prerequisites:

> - A SSH Key added to your CERN GitLab account, [see here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html) for instructions.
> - You can test if this is working by runnning `ssh -i ~/.ssh/yourPrivateKey git@gitlab.cern.ch -T -p 7999`.
>   Everything is working correctly if the output of the command is:
>
>   Welcome to GitLab, Santa Claus!