# Resolving the repositories referenced in .gitmodules

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a project with a number of submodules and I have a small issue resolving them on Jenkins, so ..

Is there any way conditionally resolve/specify submodules in.gitmodules file?

I've got scenario where repos on Jenkins resolve via ssh protocol and locally via https,

Please advise if there is any small tricks I could apply in relation to git.

I was thinking to apply git hooks etc, but I've got feeling this could be a bit of overkill.

Comment: Not sure if I got your question right, but why not simply `git submodule init <submodule_list>`? The `<submodule_list>` is determined beforehand. Then you can do a `git submodule update` as usual.

Comment: git submodule init, as I understand, just adding a subproject to main project, I need some kind of switch between protocols which will be applied based on the environment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing https-address of submodules in .git/config to ssh-address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55241341/changing-https-address-of-submodules-in-git-config-to-ssh-address)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-submodules%5D+insteadof

Comment: Hmm... maybe you should paraphrase your question then. You'd like to resolve the repositories referenced in `.gitmodules` either via SSH or HTTPS, am I right? If yes, maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41044992/use-different-git-submodule-urls-on-different-machines/41047197) answer could help?

Comment: thank you @phd looks like what I am looking for, didn't know you can rewrite configuration in git